# Incorrect Md5sum for Opera

Tags: software-installation, opera

I checked the md5sum for the .deb I downloaded from http://www.opera.com/download/guide/?os=linux-i386, and I got 272929c189608dd22a9f61fb0000a365.  This number is not listed on http://ftp.opera.com/pub/opera-developer/info/md5sum.txt, and the only place it shows up is on a website that claims to be run by the [Swedish university computer network](http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/www/clients/Opera/info/md5sum.txt), and a few other random sites.

Is this .deb file trustworthy?  Why should I trust it if the only matching hash comes from a website that isn't Opera's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the MD5 sum you mention there:

http://ftp.opera.com/pub/opera/info/md5sum.txt

```
272929c189608dd22a9f61fb0000a365  pub/opera/linux/1216/opera_12.16.1860_i386.deb
```